# libsasl dependency issues when installing librdkafka1 via yum on aws linux machine

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to install the python confluent-kafka package using pip. I'm attempting this on an aws ec2 instance that is running amazon linux (version Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09). I'm simply doing:

```
pip install pip install confluent-kafka
```

This however produces the following error:

```
In file included from confluent_kafka/src/confluent_kafka.c:17:0:
confluent_kafka/src/confluent_kafka.h:21:32: fatal error: librdkafka/rdkafka.h: No such file or directory
 #include <librdkafka/rdkafka.h>
                                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

To resolve this, I did two things:

1) Followed the instructions on [this page](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/installation.html#rpm-packages-via-yum) and added the file /etc/yum.repos.d/confluent.repo with the contents:

```
[Confluent.dist]
name=Confluent repository (dist)
baseurl=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.0/6
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.0/archive.key
enabled=1

[Confluent]
name=Confluent repository
baseurl=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.0/archive.key
enabled=1
```

2) attempted to install the librdkafka library using this command:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install -y librdkafka1 librdkafka-devel
```

Yum spits out this error however:

```
Error: Package: librdkafka1-0.9.1_confluent3.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (Confluent.dist)
       Requires: openssl-libs
Error: Package: librdkafka1-0.9.1_confluent3.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (Confluent.dist)
       Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
```

After [some googling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html), I tried:

```
sudo ln /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3
```

This had no effect. I tried doing a yum upgrade and this also did not solve the issue. After much googling, [this kafka user group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/N_0jDfKSqpY) is the only remotely helpful thing I can find, but it sadly does not contain a solution to the problem.

I'd really like to get kafka python up and running on this instance, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Amazon Linux 2016.19 seems to be based on RHEL 6 so you will need to reference Confluent's RHEL 6 Yum repo as described in [Confluent docs](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/installation.html#rpm-packages-via-yum), namely by writing the following to `/etc/yum.repos.d/confluent`:

```
[Confluent.dist]
name=Confluent repository (dist)
baseurl=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/6
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/archive.key
enabled=1

[Confluent]
name=Confluent repository
baseurl=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/archive.key
enabled=1
```

Followed by:

```
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum install gcc librdkafka1 librdkafka-devel cyrus-sasl-devel openssl-libs python-devel
$ pip install confluent-kafka  (possibly in a virtualenv)
```

Comment: Well I'll be gosh darned, that worked! I should have mentioned in my question that I had actually created the confluent.repo file and copied over the text under the "RHEL/Centos/Oracle 6" section. I was following the docs on this page: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/installation.html#rpm-packages-via-yum which are for confluent 3.0.0. The docs in the page you linked are for 3.1.1. So the real fix was to use the correct version of confluent. I'll update my question with this info and you can update your answer so that it's more clear that the confluent version was the issue.

Comment: hm spoke too soon. I just tried a fresh reinstall of confluent-platform-2.11 using the 3.1.1 rpm repo and am getting a bunch of PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found" errors. When I point the confluent.repo file to the 3.0 urls though, they install just fine. Except for librdkafka1 which only works with the 3.1 urls. >_<

Comment: posted second question for the second issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774633/trying-to-install-confluent-platform-kafka-3-1-1-on-aws-linux-using-yum-getti