# Trying to install confluent platform (kafka) 3.1.1 on aws linux using yum. Getting PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, rpm, yum, confluent-platform

I'm following the instructions linked in [this wiki doc](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/installation.html#rpm-packages-via-yum) to install the confluent platform on my EC2 instance running amazon linux (version 2016.09). I did everything it says including:

```
$ sudo rpm --import http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/archive.key
```

Created /etc/yum.repos.d/confluent.repo with these contents:

```
[Confluent.dist]
name=Confluent repository (dist)
baseurl=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/6
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/archive.key
enabled=1

[Confluent]
name=Confluent repository
baseurl=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/archive.key
enabled=1
```

Then did

```
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum install confluent-platform-2.11
```

I am getting the following errors however:

```
Downloading packages:
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-camus-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-kafka-2.11-0.10.1.1-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-kafka-rest-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-platform-oss-2.11-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.1/confluent-schema-registry-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  confluent-kafka-2.11-0.10.1.1-1.noarch: failure: confluent-kafka-2.11-0.10.1.1-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-camus-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-camus-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-kafka-rest-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-kafka-rest-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-platform-oss-2.11-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-platform-oss-2.11-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-schema-registry-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-schema-registry-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc-3.1.2-1.noarch: failure: confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc-3.1.2-1.noarch.rpm from Confluent: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

It kind of looks like the rpm files just aren't at the location that the confluent docs say they are. It's not a problem with my internet connection or anything because when I change my confluent.repo file to point to http://packages.confluent.io/rpm/3.0 the kafka packages download just fine except for [librdkafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731752/libsasl-dependency-issues-when-installing-librdkafka1-via-yum-on-aws-linux-machi). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, not sure what else to try at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to have been a temporary glitch which has been resolved since. (If not, please report back.)

Also: You may want to report such issues to Confluent's mailing list, where you typically get faster response times for such problems than on Stack Overflow:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/confluent-platform